# Uncaught reference error when I try to instantiate an object inside node console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with Node modules for the first time. I am trying to play around with FixedWidthParser module inside Node console. I followed instrucitons from the official NPM page.

First I installed it via:
`npm install fixed-width-parser`

Then I required it in my console;
`const { FixedWidthParser } = require('fixed-width-parser');`

Then I tried to create a new object:

```
const fixedWidthParser = new FixedWidthParser([
  {
    type: 'int',
    name: 'age',
    width: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    width: 12,
  },
]);
```

But I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: fixedWidthParser is not defined` error. What is happening here?

Comment: This seems to be an error in the docs: the constuctor throws errors, that `start` is required. And if the constructor throws, `fixedWitdthParser` is indeed undefined. You should contact the developers of that package -- and probably provide the `start` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from their documentation is not good. `start` property is mandatory when instantiating a FixedWidthParser, so just add that.